# Limiting a Lua script's memory usage?

Tags: lua, sandbox

I've seen it said multiple times that there is no way to limit a Lua script's memory usage, including people jumping through hoops to prevent Lua scripts from creating functions and tables. But given that lua_newstate allows you to pass a custom allocator, couldn't one just use that to limit memory consumption? At worst, one could use an arena-based allocator and put a hard limit even on the amount of memory that could be used by fragmentation.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: "I've seen it said multiple times" Two words: Citation Needed.

Comment: The Lua wiki page on sandboxes mentions using up memory as a possible attack but doesn't mention ways to limit it: http://lua-users.org/wiki/SandBoxes . I think I misread this page where it was talking about "Looah" not Lua: http://www.sk89q.com/2010/03/sandboxed-lua-via-php/

Comment: "they're always mucking around with trying to prevent the creation of functions or tables." That's because they don't want them to create tables and functions. They want to preserve the global scope. That's a different task from just preventing memory from being used.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
 static void *l_alloc_restricted (void *ud, void *ptr, size_t osize, size_t nsize)
 {
   const int MAX_SIZE = 1024; /* set limit here */
   int *used = (int *)ud;

   if(ptr == NULL) {
     /*
      * <http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_Alloc>:
      * When ptr is NULL, osize encodes the kind of object that Lua is
      * allocating.
      *
      * Since we don’t care about that, just mark it as 0.
      */
     osize = 0;
   }

   if (nsize == 0)
   {
     free(ptr);
     *used -= osize; /* substract old size from used memory */
     return NULL;
   }
   else
   {
     if (*used + (nsize - osize) > MAX_SIZE) /* too much memory in use */
       return NULL;
     ptr = realloc(ptr, nsize);
     if (ptr) /* reallocation successful? */
       *used += (nsize - osize);
     return ptr;
   }
 }
```

To make Lua use your allocator, you can use

```
 int *ud = malloc(sizeof(int)); *ud = 0;
 lua_State *L = lua_State *lua_newstate (l_alloc_restricted, ud);
```

Note: I haven't tested the source, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks, though what I was wondering about is why I've never seen anyone use this technique; they're always mucking around with trying to prevent the creation of functions or tables.

Comment: Now that I've looked again, it appears that the reason is that people are trying to sandbox code from within Lua.

Comment: I think the int you malloc really wants to be zeroed before use

Comment: You're forgetting a very important piece of the lua_Alloc spec: When ptr is NULL, osize encodes the kind of object that Lua is allocating http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_Alloc

Comment: @davidking The example given on that link does not treat that case in a special way.

Comment: @heinrich5991 that's because the example there doesn't use the sizes at all (and even has a comment that says so), so it doesn't have to treat them at all. But it does have the sentence I quoted about osize being special that the Lua code you pasted here gets wrong. Your code will cause the used size to appear to go negative because it doesn't use osize properly with ptr==NULL like the docs say. This version https://gist.github.com/ketralnis/4c177babb16ff77b6b7a does it correctly. I'm showing you this because I used your code and found the bug happening in practise.

Comment: @davidking Thanks! I incorporated it into the answer, if that's okay with you.